# Bootstrap Popover: Align on top right

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to align Bootstrap Popover on top right?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/8tyxyfds/)

```
$('.well').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.popover({
      placement: 'right',
      html: true,
      content: $this.find('.tip').html()
    })
});
```

**This is what I am trying to do:**

[image]

**Instead of this:**

[image]

I've tried a lot of suggestions but any of them are working unfortunately.

Comment: What *all suggestions* have you tried?

Comment: Don't you have a code to show us?

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/8tyxyfds/

Answer (score 0):

There's another reason too. Bootstrap has a **bug**! Update your Bootstrap CSS to make it work. Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tyxyfds/2/) here.

---

Change the `data-container="body"` to your parent. You have to show your code to get help! In your code, use:

```
data-container="parent-selector" // Instead of the default!
```

The [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) says:

> Appends the popover to a specific element. Example: container: 'body'. This option is particularly useful in that it allows you to position the popover in the flow of the document near the triggering element - which will prevent the popover from floating away from the triggering element during a window resize.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="#idofparent"
        data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"
        data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>
```

Comment: @brunodd Which version?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed doing it on the traditional way:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/5t19g403/5/)

```
$('div.tip').hide();          

$('.display-tooltip').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div.tip').fadeOut('medium');
});

$('.display-tooltip').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div.tip').fadeIn( "slow");
});
```